# Giving sub query returing too many rows error while i'm updating same table with using some values from table

Tags: oracle, ora-01427

The below query returning

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

```
UPDATE master 
   SET final = NVL(final,
              (SELECT 'Disconnect' 
                 FROM  (SELECT NVL(Ported_out_flag, type) as type, 
                               CASE WHEN order = 'C'  THEN 'C' ELSE service end service,
                               cdms
                          FROM master) 
                WHERE type in ('PORTED_OUT')
                  AND (service in ('C','I') or service is null)
                  AND cdms in ('FR','IS','RE','QU')
              )
             );
```

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Laying it out more readably highlights the issue. The innermost query returns all rows from `MASTER`. Presumably there is more than one row in it.

Comment: When I'm selecting SELECT 'Disconnect' 
                 FROM  (SELECT NVL(Ported_out_flag, type) as type, 
                          CASE WHEN order = 'C'  THEN 'C' ELSE service end service,cdms
                          FROM master) 
 WHERE type in ('PORTED_OUT') 
   and (service in ('C','I') or service is null)
   and cdms in ('FR','IS','RE','QU')    will giving me correct results, but updating is not working

Comment: By 'correct results', do you mean exactly one row?

Comment: By the way, the `set final = nvl(final, (select ...))` construction looks like you want to update rows where final is null, and the `select 'Disconnect'` makes me wonder if it should be something like `update master set final = 'Disconnect' where final is null and exists...`.